# How to run parallel tasks on Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, parallel-processing

I'm building a WP8 app and I need to perform around 30 web requests. These requests don't depend on each other so they could be parallelized.

My code looks like this (simplified/pseudocode):

```
foreach (Uri uri in uris)
{
    var rawData = await Task.Run(() => httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false));

    var processedData = dataProcessor.Process(rawData);
    processedDataCollection.Add(processedData);
}
```

When I look at Fiddler, the requests are all performed sequantial; it takes a few seconds to perform and process all of them. However, I don't want the code to wait until 1 request is finished before moving to the next one, I want to perform multiple requests at the same time.

Normally I would use `Parallel.Invoke()` or `Parallel.ForEach()` or something like that to do this, but apparently the Parallel library is not available in Windows Phone 8.

So what's the best way to accomplish this? `Task.Factory.StartNew()`? `new Thread()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no need to run each request on a separate thread. You can just as easily do this:

```
var raw = await Task.WhenAll(uris.Select(uri => httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri)));
var processed = raw.Select(data => dataProcessor.Process(data)).ToArray();
```

This code takes the collection of `uris` and starts an HTTP download for each one (`Select(...)`). Then it asynchronously waits for them all to complete (`WhenAll`). All the data is then processed in the second line of code.

However, it's likely that the Windows Phone runtime will limit the maximum number of requests you can have to the same server.

Comment: I really like this one. Very compact and elegant. I couldn't really get it working with the other code, but this works perfectly. Your post would just be a bit more helpful if you could explain the steps, and why it's actually working.

Comment: Updated to include more explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `await` with the task that you create - which means you are waiting for the call to finish before you continue the method. Your `foreach` isn't parallelized, as you noted, so what you're essentially doing here is a number of serial requests.

You could make this run as you (probably) intend using the `Task.WaitAll` method. Something like this should suffice:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (Uri uri in uris)
{
    var thisTask = Task.Run(() => 
                       { 
                         httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
                         var processedData = dataProcessor.Process(rawData);
                         processedDataCollection.Add(processedData);
                       });

    tasks.Add(thisTask);
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Do note that this also parallelizes the processing of your data (that is, it will call `.Process` in parallel also), which your original code did not.

I'd also add that you probably *don't* want to run 30 requests at once, unless they're to different servers. Making 30 simultaneous requests to Uris on the same server is unlikely to improve your processing time. (Fortunately, the TPL will likely take care of this for you as it'll limit the parallelism somewhat.)

Comment: What does GetStringAsync() return in your example? I can only get it to return a `Task<T>` or `ConfiguredTaskAwaitable<T>`. How do I use that for the Process() method? Do I need to call `.Result` on the `GetStringAsync` method?

Comment: And isn't it better to use `await Task.WhenAll` instead of `Task.WaitAll`? Or do they have different results?

Comment: `Task.WhenAll` creates a new task that won't complete until all the others have finished; `Task.WaitAll` just waits for them to complete. If you don't care when they complete and can carry on regardless, you can omit that call entirely.  Regarding `GetStringAsync`....

Comment: ... All I'd done was wrap the code you're already calling to show how you can make it run in parallel. You're not *doing* anything with the return value and you havne't really specified what you *want* to do, so I didn't change that code. `GetStringAsync` returns a task, because it's an asynchronous method. If you want to get the result you can use `string s = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);` - I'm not sure what your intention was with calling `.ConfigureAwait(false)`.