# Parallel in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have used in the past for Windows Phone 7 apps the [System.Threading.Tasks.3.0.1 library](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks/3.0.1) but they don't seem to have a new update that works with Windows 8, so I am not sure if it is now built in or what.

This is what I use to do with the library

```
     Parallel.Invoke(() => Dispose());


 public void Dispose()
    {
        if (photoCamera != null)
        {
            photoCamera.Dispose();
            photoCamera.Initialized -= PhotoCameraOnInitialized;
            photoCamera.AutoFocusCompleted -= PhotoCameraOnAutoFocusCompleted;
            photoCamera = null;


            recScanArea.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the point of parallely invoking Dispose() ?

Comment: Because in my app I had a panorama view and without one with a barcode scanner view and another without it, if you would switch between the 2 and try to turn off the barcode scanner there would be a lag and it made for a bad experience, by using Parallel I was able to switch to the other view and then let it shut off the barcode scanner code in parallel.

Comment: Why don't you wrap your call inside `using` so it gets disposed as early as possible, or you can't ?

Comment: No I don't think that would solve it as then after it would be created it would dispose itself in the same method where them switch could happen way after initialization. Also I am unregistering events in my Dispose method as well as disposing.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly everything has moved to the TPL library and the use of async on WP8.

[Take a look at this Q/A on this very issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288391/how-to-run-parallel-tasks-on-windows-phone)

It looks like the [Parallel class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel(v=vs.110).aspx) is available in the PCL library so I think you should be able to find it or add it to your WP8 application.

Answer (score 0):

The best wait to do is using async/await that presents the best way to implement Tasks in .NET Framework 4.5.

So, I recommend to you [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Parallel processing is overkill if you just want to run some code on a background thread. "Small" targets such as mobile devices do not (and should not) support full parallel processing.

First, I *suspect* that your initial code didn't do anything different than if you had just invoked `Dispose` directly. Parallel invocation will include the calling thread as one of its "workers"; it does *not* free up the calling thread to do other work. Also, setting `Visibility` and accessing `PhotoCamera` almost certainly need to be done on the UI thread. So, I bet that your "parallel" code was in fact not parallel at all. I'd give this a try first:

```
Dispose();
```

If you are absolutely certain that you want to execute `Dispose` on a background thread, you can use `Task.Run`:

```
await Task.Run(() => Dispose());
```