# Windows phone 8 - Download html code not wating

Tags: c#, http, windows-phone-8, web

I need to download 5 pieces of HTML before continuing to process this data. How can I rewrite this code to wait for all downloads to complete before continuing?

```
public string izvuci_sliku(string linka)
{
     WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
     link = "";
     webclient.DownloadStringCompleted += webclient_DownloadStringCompleted3;
     webclient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(linka));
     //wait upper line and then go one
     return "";
}
```

Comment: don't use async calls, then...

Comment: `.downloadstring()`...

Comment: 'System.Net.WebClient' does not contain a definition for 'DownloadString' and no extension method 'DownloadString' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.WebClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) --> This is windows phone 8 not desktop application.

Comment: Figures... well, there would have to be an synchronous version somewhere. otherwise you're stuck with using callbacks or completion handlers or whatever it is that you set up to handle the async response.

Comment: clarify the question

Comment: I want synchronous download of html code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a legacy of silverlight. You will need to to perform asynchronous calls, but you can do this in a way that looks more like synchronous code within your method by using `await` and the TPL.

Refer to Stephen Cleary's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288391/how-to-run-parallel-tasks-on-windows-phone) for an example of how this works.